# Compare column with cell returning a false true array

Tags: arrays, excel, compare, libreoffice

I have a column like this in excel

```
 A     
1Sex
2Female
3Female
4Male
5Female
```

And in B1 I have 'Male'

I am doing this =(A2:A5=B1)
I want something like {FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE} in one row
I am using LibreOffice

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a formula that will return `False, False, True, False` in a single cell? Or can it be a list, of say `B2` is `False` since `A2` is Female?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: In Excel:  Highlight four cells in a row with the first activated.  Put `=TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$5)=$B$1` in the first cell then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  If done properly Excel will put the formula in all four cells and put `{}` around the formula.  I added this because of the excel tag.

Comment: for a non array formula: Put this in the first cell `=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,COLUMN(A:A))=$B$1` and drag across.

Comment: BruceWayne,  I want {FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE} in a single cell

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner's array formula works exactly the same in Open Office / Libre Office

```
=TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$5)=$B$1
```

The non-array formula is

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5;COLUMN(A1))=$B$1
```

Comment: Actually I want to do this =(A2:A5=B1); I saw examples and this should return FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE in only one cell, but it is not working for me.

Comment: It is easy in Google Sheets and should also be in the latest version of Excel (which I don't yet have). Not sure about Libre Office - will test it later when I have access to it.